# Is it possible to disable kill option from GNOME System Monitor context menu?

Tags: kill, gnome-system-monitor

Is there a way to prevent [Gnome System Monitor](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SystemMonitor) from providing `kill` option in the context menu for a given process ?

If you can't help but asking why I want this, I was assigned the (perplexing) task of trying to prevent the execution of kill [specific process] for root/users with elevated privileges throughout the system. Apart from this sounding illogical, I have been reading posts that describe that this is not only not possible but detrimental.

So I decided to approach this by collecting evidences to corroborate the inviability of this, by breaking it into:

1. prevent execution of kill from command line
2. **prevent killing of process from GUI**
3. prevent stopping systemd
4. in my app (a .NET app which runs as a systemd daemon), intercept the kernel signal sent to the process upon running kill (perhaps calling sigaction) so to ignore the kill request.

This question tries to clear item number 2: does System Monitor offer the possibility of hiding/customizing commands from its context menu, such as `kill`, out-of-the-box ?

[image]

Comment: This uses [the `org.gnome.gnome-system-monitor.kill` Polkit action](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-system-monitor/-/blob/master/org.gnome.gnome-system-monitor.policy.in.in#L10) - what you should do is disallow that action for your target users using Polkit.

Comment: I don't think you can use polkit to block root.

Comment: @user10489: I am guessing he meant disabling the policy will prevent it from being shown to non-root users.